# When I insert a field into crystal report and that's the code the field does not appear in the report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

This is the code on the print command 
and the dataset connected with database successfully

```
Try
            Dim rpt As New rptallergy2
            Dim myConnection As SqlConnection
            Dim MyCommand1 As New SqlCommand()
            Dim myDA1 As New SqlDataAdapter()
            Dim myDS As New DataSet
            myConnection = New SqlConnection(cs)

            MyCommand1.Connection = myConnection
            MyCommand1.CommandText = "SELECT RTRIM(patient.name) from patient  "
            MyCommand1.CommandType = CommandType.Text

            myDA1.SelectCommand = MyCommand1

            myDA1.Fill(myDS, "patient")

            rpt.SetDataSource(myDS)
            frmReport.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
            frmReport.ShowDialog()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: this field dose not appear in the report

Comment: Your SQL returns an unnamed field because it depends on the function.  You will need to use an alias, to match the name that your crystal report is expecting as the name of the field.

Comment: i used where statement and the problem still presist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MyCommand1.CommandText = "SELECT RTRIM(patient.name) as pName from patient"
```

Then match the `pName` field to the field on your crystal reports is what Jonathan Willcock was saying.